# Flex Spark DataGrid: ReferenceError #1069 in GridItemEditor

Tags: datagrid, flex4, flex-spark, itemeditor

I'm coding a generic `<s:GridItemEditor>` for spark DataGrid, to create dynamically an appropiate UIComponent for edition, depending on properties types.

Some properties linked to GridColumn's are complex, like:

```
var gridColumn:GridColumn = new GridColumn("Category.Description");
```

I'm having this error with this complex properties:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property Category.Description not found on GOClases.Person and there is no default value.....
```

at spark.components.gridClasses::GridItemEditor/set data()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\gridClasses\GridItemEditor.as:176]**

This is the specific function where this error ocurrs:

```
public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    _data = value;

    if (_data && column.dataField)
    {
        this.value = _data[column.dataField];
    }
}
```

Is it possible to avoid this error redefining properly the set data() function?
How can I workaround this?

Is it possible to define differents properties as label and itemEditor in spark DataGrid?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved: it's make more sense assign Object type properties to GridColumn's dataField `var gridColumn:GridColumn = new GridColumn("Category")`; and use labelFunction to evaluate dynamically complex properties, I used r1.deval.D library here to resolve it:

```
private function funcionEtiqueta(item:Object, column:GridColumn):String
{
     D.eval(complexProperty,item).toString();
}
```

Maybe this would help somebody else.
Thanks.